# how to join tables when the join is on 2 fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
A  (productid  partid)

B  (productid  partid)
```

I want to insert to table `C (productid  partid)` all rows that appear in both `A` and `B`. Then delete these rows from `B`.

for example:

```
A
productid  partid
  1         100
  1         101
  2         200
  3         300

B
productid  partid
  1         100
  2         200
  4         400
  4         401
```

You can assume that each couple (productid,partid) can't appear more than once in each table.

===== after query runs ====

`C` will be:

```
productid  partid
  1         100
  2         200
```

`B` will be:

```
productid  partid
  4         400
  4         401
```

What I tried to do is:

```
Insert into C (productid,partid) (select productid,partid from A join B on ???? )
```

My issue is that I don't know how to join tables on more than one column?
and I don't know how to do both insert and delete on same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Insert into C, the query used above is correct-

```
Insert into C (productid,partid) 
select A.productid, A.partid 
from A join B on A.productid = B.productid AND A.partid = B.partid
```

To delete from B, you can use the below query-

```
Delete B from B
join C
on C.productid = B.productid 
AND C.partid = B.partid
```

Since you have to delete the records in B so you have to give that in delete statement.

Answer (score 2):

You simply use needed columns from both tables and use them with `AND` operator:

```
Insert into C (productid,partid) 
select A.productid, A.partid 
from A join B on A.productid = B.productid AND A.partid = B.partid
```

Comment: is it possible on the same query to delete from B all rows that were inserted to C?

Comment: @java I don't know of a way to do it in the same query. I would run a separate `DELETE` query and delete records from B that have matching records in C

Comment: How do you do that? I an't figure out how to set the WHERE on the DELETE.